# How to get XADatasource from a DB2 database hosted on Websphere 6.1

Tags: transactions, db2, websphere, jndi, jta

I am working on distributed transactions. I am trying to implement XA transaction using Atomikos as the Transaction Manager. One of my issues is being able to get a "XADataSource" from the DB2 database hosted on the Websphere 6.1 server.
I am using jndi lookup to get the Datasource as below:

```
Context ctx=new InitialContext();
XADataSource ds = (XADataSource) ctx.lookup(dataSourceName);
```

However, this lookup causes the following exception:

```
[3/21/12 12:08:47:551 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource incompatible with javax.sql.XADataSource
[3/21/12 12:08:47:551 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.BusinessEntities.JndiConn.<init>(JndiConn.java:21)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:551 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.Servlet.InitialServlet.doGet(InitialServlet.java:41)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:551 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.Servlet.InitialServlet.doPost(InitialServlet.java:186)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:551 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:551 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:551 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1101)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:569)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3440)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:267)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:815)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1461)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:118)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:102)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)
[3/21/12 12:08:47:566 EDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)
```

The same works fine if attribute "ds" is of type DataSource instead of XADataSource. But I want get XAConnections and hence require XADataSource. I have tried searching a lot but am unable to figure out how to avoid this cast exception.
Any pointers on what i should do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to cast it to XADataSource.

Both XADataSource and regular DataSource are available to you as a WSJdbcDataSource.

WSJdbcDataSource implements WSDataSource which in turn extends DataSource.

The connection that you have is still XA enabled if the underlying JDBC Driver hosting this datasource is XA enabled.

Sorry I am not able to provide you with ways to getting the XADataSource as that is likely not available.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to manage the XADataSource/XAConnection yourself?  Instead, begin a UserTransaction, obtain a normal DataSource, obtain a normal Connection, do your work, and then commit the UserTransaction.  UserTransaction will cause XA to be used under the covers.

Comment: I am trying to hadnle the TM myself rather than using another API like Atomikos. Hence require XADataSource. 
UserTransaction using DataSource works fine but I dnt wanna implement tht.

Comment: In that case, I doubt there's a way to use container-managed data sources reliably, since RRA is going to assume it has full control of the transaction interaction.  You're probably better off using DriverManager or directly interacting with DB2 classes.

Comment: @Andy: What are you actually trying to achieve (hat is not already provided by WebSphere's transaction manager)?

Comment: @Andreas: I want to use Atomikos as a TM and let its classes handle te enlistment/delistment of resources. Atomikos data source requires an object of type XADataSource, which I am not able to get from the jndi lookup.

This is the code right now:
`Context ctx = new InitialContext();
ds = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
ds.setXaDataSource((XADataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/dataSource1"));`

but it throws the following Exception:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource incompatible with javax.sql.XADataSource`

Comment: Then I stand by my comment above: I doubt there's a way to use container-managed data sources reliably.

Comment: @Andy: Yes, but why do you want to embed your own transaction manager into your application, and not use WebSphere's transaction manager?

Comment: @Andreas: I wanted to explore the possiblity of having my app server and TM different. But I have given up using Atomikos for now and started using WAS to carry on with the project..will still b open to try a 3rd party TM if i get the XADataSource object somehow.
Thnx for the info